# Can't solve: 'Redefinition of NULL macro'

Tags: c

I'm working on a big project and I have this warning:

```
...\include\stddef.h" 38/9] macro "NULL" redefined
...\ncs_types.h" 125/13] previous definition of macro "NULL"
```

In the first file `stddef.h` which comes from a compiler installation folder I have this:

```
#ifdef  __cplusplus
#define NULL    (0)
#else   /* defined(__cplusplus) */
#define NULL    ((void *) 0)
#endif  /* defined(__cplusplus) */
```

I'm not allowed to modify this file.

Now in the other file which is part of the application code(which I'm allowed to modify. So I have to get rid of this warning by doing something in the file from the application code and don't touch the other one) I have this:

```
/* NULL pointer definition if not already defined */
#ifndef NULL
    /* Deviation MISRA-2 */
    #define NULL   0
#endif
```

And then I get that warning. I cannot get rid of it. I have tried things such as:
- undefining the macro in my file from the application -> same warning
- including an #ifndef guard -> same warning
- undefining the macro in my application file if '__cplusplus' is not defined - > same warning
- in my application file I have tried defining the macro to void pointer type instead of pure '0'.
  Like this:

```
#ifndef NULL
    /* Deviation MISRA-2 */
    #define NULL    ((void *) 0)
#endif
```

From what I know if you redefine a macro to the same thing that it was already defined there should be no warning from the compiler. However, if I do this I get an `incompatible types at argument` error somewhere in the project. Apparently I need the NULL macro to be defined as '0' and not casted to a void pointer type.

Please if possible help me understand why I get that warning and how can I remove it. Also please help me understand this:
If in my application file I have the #ifndef NULL...guard why is the macro getting redefined anyway(since it is already defined in the header file from the compiler)? Shouldn't the preprocessor skip that line that redefines NULL? I'm very confused about this.

Also one note: I'm getting this warning not once but several times when I build my project. Same warning about the same two files. I guess it has something to do about how the files are included in the build script. Please give me some ideas on what to investigate to understand the problem.

Thank you very much for reading my long post ☺. I'm sorry I cannot give further details as this is a work related project.

Comment: Is `ncs_types.h` included before other files? Have you tried moving the `#include` down a bit?

Comment: I usually do first includes of `<>` headers (in alphabetical order), then the `""` header files. (Note "headers" and "header files": not a mistake!)

Comment: Is it a C compiler/linker error or is it a MISRA-C diagnostic error? Because MISRA-C doesn't allow re-definition of NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...\include\stddef.h" 38/9] macro "NULL" redefined
...\ncs_types.h" 125/13] previous definition of macro "NULL"
```

This is telling you that `NULL` is initially defined in `ncs_types.h` and then *redefined* in `stddef.h`. The ordering of the error messages is a little confusing.

You have three options:

1. Don't define `NULL` in your header file at all. It'll be defined later, by `stddef.h`. This probably won't work if you're using `NULL` in that header.
2. Include `stddef.h` *before* your header file.
3. Include `stddef.h` *in* your header file, instead of defining `NULL`.

Comment: A third option to remove the definition of `NULL` from `ncstypes.h`  and `#include <stddef.h>` at or before that point *in that header file*.    That is the option I'd choose, given that the content of `ncs_types.h` relies on `NULL` being defined, to avoid errors due to forgetting to `#include <stddef.h>` before `#include "ncs_types.h"`.  Including standard headers multiple times, directly or indirectly, is not a problem.

Comment: Edited to include that third option.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
/* NULL pointer definition if not already defined */
#ifndef NULL
    /* Deviation MISRA-2 */
    #define NULL   0
#endif
```

into

```
#include <stddef.h>
```

1. You have the error because your file is included before `stddef.h`. So first your file defines NULL, then `stddef.h` defines null, because the order is important.
2. Don't define NULL yourself. Just include `stddef.h` file. It has the `NULL` symbol waiting for you.

Answer (score 1):

Standard includes don't expect `NULL` to be defined, unlike your custom include.

So you should first include standard includes *then* your custom include.

Note that `NULL` has to be defined in `stddef.h` so you can scrap your own definition of `NULL` altogether and include `stddef.h` wherever `NULL` is required.